# pwntools: Use gdb api to interrupt a process

Tags: python, gdb, pwntools

When running `gdb cmd` I can manually stop `cmd` via Ctrl-C.  This invokes the debugger and lets me inspect memory.

In pwntools, I can attach gdb, and can manually stop the process by hitting Ctrl-C in the gdb window.  I'd like to be able to do this programatically from pwntools script: something like:

```
if output != expected:
    io.gdb.ctrlc() # break, let me use gdb
```

This doesn't necessarily require a pwntools answer.  GDB has a powerful Python API, but I can't find in it the equivalent of a "Interrupt the process, as if someone hit Ctrl-C".  Is there a way to do that, either via the GDB Python API or via a pwntools method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can send a signal to gdb to simulate hitting Ctrl-C in the gdb window

prepare a file gdb_run3s:

```
#let shell send a signal to the parent process, which is the gdb, after 3 seconds
shell sleep 3 && kill -SIGINT $PPID &  
#continue, should break by signal SIGINT 3 seconds later
c  
#now can read/write register/memory 
set $pc=xxx
```

then source it in gdb

```
(gdb) source gdb_run3s
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to do that, either via the GDB Python API or via a pwntools method?

I don't know about `pwntools`, but using the GDB Python API in *all-stop* mode this would not be possible: when the inferior is running, GDB is *blocked* (waiting for something to happen to the inferior with `waitpid`).

It *might* work in [non-stop mode](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Non_002dStop-Mode.html) though.

Comment: Hitting Ctrl-C in the gdb window works, so there must be some way to do the same programatically.

Comment: @SRobertJames "Hitting Crtl-C ... there must be ..." -- your conclusion does not _at all_ follow. What happens in Ctrl-C is rather complicated, but ends up unblocking GDBs `waitpid` in exactly the same way as inferior getting a `SIGSEGV` or hitting a breakpoint would.

Comment: Could I just send the signal to the inferior, then?

Comment: @SRobertJames Sure. Just not from GDB itself (since GDB is blocked).